# UICollectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect and layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm implementing a custom flow layout. It has 2 main methods for overriding to determine placement of cells: `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`.

In my code, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` is called, but `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` isn't. What determines which gets called? Where does `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` get called?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` doesn't necessarily call `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`.

In fact, if you subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, the flow layout will prepare the layout and cache the resulting attributes. So, when `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` is called, it won't ask `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`, but just uses the cached values.

If you want to ensure that the layout attributes are always modified according to your layout, implement a modifier for both `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  NSArray *attributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
  for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *cellAttributes in attributesInRect) {
    [self modifyLayoutAttributes:cellAttributes];
  }
  return attributesInRect;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [self modifyLayoutAttributes:attributes];
  return attributes;
}

- (void)modifyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes
{
  // Adjust the standard properties size, center, transform etc.
  // Or subclass UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and add additional attributes.
  // Note, that a subclass will require you to override copyWithZone and isEqual.
  // And you'll need to tell your layout to use your subclass in +(Class)layoutAttributesClass
}
```

Comment: What if I need the index path to determine the rect property of the attribute? I have no way of passing the index path into the modify function.

Comment: A `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` has the `indexPath` property.

Comment: @Robert Doesn't [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect] return nil? That's the impression I got from the APple docs.

Comment: @moonman239 `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect]` returns valid layout attributes when used on a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It returns `nil` when used on a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`. 

If you write your own layout based on `UICollectionViewLayout` you can create blank layout attributes using `[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:]`.